# TCP sockets (client-server) recv() returning -1 value

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, client-server

Please guide me why is blocking function **recv()** not waiting for message from client. Instead it is returning value **-1**. Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

**Server code (partial):**

```
    (call to getaddrinfo) // struct addrinfo hints, *res

    int sfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    if(sfd == -1)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed .....");
        exit(-3);
    }
    fcntl(sfd, F_SETFL, ~O_NONBLOCK);

    if (setsockopt(sfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        herror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
    }

    bind(sfd,res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if(listen(sfd, BACKLOG)!=0)
    {
        printf("Listen Error");
        exit(-4);
    }
    printf("\n\nListening on port: %s\n\n", argv[1]);
    struct sockaddr_storage clientAddr;
    socklen_t addrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int connFD = accept(sfd,(struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &addrSize); // connection successful
    char buffer[10] = "Hello!";
    write(connFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer)); // message sent to client
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    int bytesReceived;
    if((bytesReceived = recv(sfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) == -1)  // Problem starts here
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not retrieve message from client.");
        exit(-5);
    }
```

Comment: Any diagnostics on `int connFD = accept(...`?

Comment: Connection successful. No problem there.

Comment: Learn about `errno`, `perror()` and `strerror()`.

Comment: @Apprentice You should include that part in the example. People (I mean me) react instintivly when they see code like that without error checking.

Comment: And, make the example a [mcve] please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that you are calling recv on wrong socket (sfd) should be (connFD)

fix:

```
if((bytesReceived = recv(connFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0)) == -1)
```

Comment: +1 Probably the problem the asker's looking for, and if not  still a problem the asker needs to be made aware of.